# issues with php form

Tags: php, html, forms

I am trying to complete a form.

I want someone to go below and fill out info
t1.html

After they fill out info, they will see a Thankyou for submission
(right now it goes to a php page of what they entered)

Someone will get an email ('email address that the email goes to' in the form) with a link of a php page that has what was entered from the form.

That person who gets the email will then accept or deny on that php page.

I am missing how to generate the php page, so the person receiving the email will be able to access info of what was entered into the form. How do I do that?

form

```
    <form name="iform" method="post" action="html_form1.php" class="iform">

    <ul>

    <li><label for="SendingeWarrant">Sending  to:</label><input class="itext"         type="text" name="SendingeWarrant" id="SendingeWarrant" /></li>
    <li class="iseparator">&nbsp;</li>
    <li>
    <label for="Email">Email Address  that the email goes to:</label><input   class="itext" type="text" name="Email" id="Email" />
    </li>
    <li class="iseparator">&nbsp;</li>
    <li><label>&nbsp;</label><input type="Submit" name="Submit" value="Submit" /></li>
    </ul></form>
```

php

```
     <?php
     if (!empty($_POST)) {


$success = $error = false;


$post = new stdClass;


foreach ($_POST as $key => $val)
    $post->$key = trim(strip_tags($_POST[$key]));

// Check for blank fields
if ( empty($post->Email))
    $error = true;

else {

    // Get this directory, to include other files from
    $dir = dirname(__FILE__);

    // Get the contents of the pdf into a variable for later
    ob_start();
    require_once($dir.'/pdf.php');
    $pdf_html = ob_get_contents();
    ob_end_clean();

    // Load the dompdf files
    require_once($dir.'/dompdf/dompdf_config.inc.php');

    $dompdf = new DOMPDF(); // Create new instance of dompdf
    $dompdf->load_html($pdf_html); // Load the html
    $dompdf->render(); // Parse the html, convert to PDF
    $pdf_content = $dompdf->output(); // Put contents of pdf into variable for   later

    // Get the contents of the HTML email into a variable for later
    ob_start();
    require_once($dir.'/html3.php');
    $html_message = ob_get_contents();
    ob_end_clean();

    // Load the SwiftMailer files
    require_once($dir.'/swift/swift_required.php');

    $mailer = new Swift_Mailer(new Swift_MailTransport()); // Create new instance of SwiftMailer

    $message = Swift_Message::newInstance()
                   ->setSubject('eWarrant') // Message subject
                   ->setTo(array($post->Email => $post- >SendingeWarrant)) // Array of people to send to
                   ->setFrom(array('no-reply@henschen.com' =>  'eWarrant')) // From:
                   ->setBody($html_message, 'text/html'); // Attach  that HTML message from earlier


    // Send the email, and show user message
    if ($mailer->send($message))
        $success = true;
    else
        $error = true;

  }

      }
      ?>


     <html>
        <head>
<style>
body {font-family:Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; font-size:10pt;}
table {width:100%; border-collapse:collapse; border:1px solid #CCC;}
td {padding:5px; border:1px solid #CCC; border-width:1px 0;}
</style>
    </head>
       <body>

<h1></h1>

<table>
    <tr>
        <td><strong>Name of person sending to:</strong></td>
        <td><?php echo $_POST["SendingeWarrant"]; ?></td>
        <td><strong>Email being sent to:</strong></td>
        <td><?php echo $_POST["Email"]; ?></td>
    </tr>
</table>

<p>Approve / Deny</p>

    </body>
    </html>
    </body>
    </html>
```

email php file

```
    <html>
    <body>

    <p style="font-family:Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;font-size:"x-small";"><?php echo   $post->SendingeWarrant; ?></p>
      <p style="font-family:Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;font-size:"x-small";">Click  link to approve or deny:  </p>

    </body>
      </html>
```

Comment: Have you heard of SQL?

Comment: heard of it, but not familiar with it

Comment: You should definitely start using sql

Comment: You'll need to learn how to store the data in a database, so it can be retrieved later on. There are literally thousands of tutorials out there a [simple google search away](https://www.google.com.au/#q=php+store+data+in+database), so I don't believe anybody needs to write yet another tutorial just for you. Do a search, learn how to store your data in a database for later retrieval, then if you have troubles come back and ask a question. For now, I'm voting to close this question.

Comment: thank you yes I will close. I didn't know i need sql

Answer (score 0):

Enter the email data in your database and when person receiving the email will click the accept button it will take that data from database.